# Deserialization and correctness of the design

Tags: c++, serialization, architecture, boost-serialization

What I have now is a small library which able to load, save object graphs, manage object's lifetime, GCs unused objects. It uses boost.serialization

- In ideal universe input is always valid, in my part of universe some data may become invalid (the keys in `map<Key, ObjectRef>` can become invalid. `ObjectRef` is intrusive shared pointer).
- In the process of loading `ar >> _some_objects` (`_some_objects` is a STL container of type `std::map<Key, ObjectRef>`) if the keys become invalid, ObjectRef's destructor releases its underlying object via `Object::release`. Simply because the keys become equal and std::map can't hold equal keys.
- `Object::release` accesses some services (to add the object into object-destroy-queue for ex.) which aren't ready to use yet as de-serialization is not complete. The whole thing is that low-level de-serialization invokes such high-level user code is bad!
- The worst thing is that if object-destroy-queue will be de-serialized later, during the process of loading boost.serialization will clear queue's containers

```

```
void SomeClass::load(Archive& ar, int version) {
    // _some_objects is std::map<Key, ObjectRef>
    ar >> _some_objects;
}

void Object::release() {
   // also accesses some services (something like destroy queue)
   // which aren't ready to use as de-serialization is not complete
}
```

```

How do I prevent low-level code from triggering high-level calls? It is ok to invoke `Object::release`, but not when the whole system is in some inconsistent state. Thanks

- I can just block from `Object::release` from accessing anything, or delay calls somehow
- Test if the key is valid, and then and only in this case load ObjectRef
- Don't use boost.serialization, use something like protobufs. Reconstruct everything manually, in proper order